# Octokit GitHub API: restrict who can push to a branch

Tags: ruby, github, branch, github-api, octokit

I'm using the `octokit` gem to communicate with the GitHub API and am trying to find a way to restrict who can push to a protected branch. I've attached a screenshot of where this is done in the web console:

[image]

My problem is that at the moment I can't find a way to do this with `octokit`. Anyone know if I've missed something or if this is something that isn't possible through the API yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not missing anything -- it's not available via the API yet, but it is something we'd like to provide. Follow the blog for updates: https://developer.github.com/changes/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the API call to [add a user restriction](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/#add-user-restrictions-of-protected-branch) was recently added. You should be able to add this to the `octokit` gem.